# APACHE-DJANGO-WSGI Deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a django app located at

/home/user/myapp

I'm trying to run the app with apache2 and WSGI. Currently, the apache2 configuration is at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and has this directory relating to my webiste

```
    <VirtualHost website.com:80>
   ServerName website.com
   ServerAlias www.website.com
   ServerAdmin email@website.com

   DocumentRoot /home/user/myapp/static

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/website-directory/django.wsgi
   <Directory /home/user/myapp/static>
  Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /robots.txt /var/www/webisite-directory/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/webisite-directory/favicon.ico
   Alias /images /home/user/myapp/images
   Alias /static /home/user/myapp/static

   ErrorLog /var/www/webisite-directory/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/webisite-directory/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My django.wsgi is

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/user/myapp')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '/myapp_directory/settings'
sys.executable = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is my error log

```
  user@ubuntu:/var/www/website-directory$ vim error.log
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060478 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] self.load_middleware(), referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060490 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 48, in load_middleware, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060509 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] if settings.MIDDLEWARE is None:, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060521 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060558 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] self._setup(name), referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060570 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060585 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module), referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060597 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060612 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE), referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060624 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060642 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] __import__(name), referer: http://www.mywebsite
[Thu Mar 30 01:25:10.060705 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 7235:tid 139856399259392] [client 98.16.70.181:51796] ImportError: Import by filename is not supported., referer: http://www.mywebsite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be a module, as the name implies, not a path.

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp_directory.settings'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now to figure out why the apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Most likely because you aren't telling mod_wsgi where you project is for imports. Recommended you switch to daemon mode of mod_wsgi and then use ``python-path`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` to say where your project code is. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: The immediate problem is that you should be getting `application` by calling `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()`, rather than instantiating WSGIHandler directly.